# Keeping a component 50% bottom to its top component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a profile page ui, Where the profile data like name and bio container will stay 50% to the bottom of its top component which is cover picture right now.

So this is my React Native code,

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.coverContainer}>

        </View>
        <View style={styles.profileDataContainer}>

        </View>
        <View style={styles.intrestsContainer}>

        </View>
        <View style={styles.topicsContainer}>

        </View>
      </View>
```

And current styles,

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {

  },
  coverContainer: {
      height : 200,
      backgroundColor : 'blue'
  },
  profileDataContainer: {
      marginHorizontal : 30,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      height : 200,
      shadowColor: "#e5e5e5",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2
      },
      shadowRadius: 2,
      shadowOpacity: 1.0,
      elevation : 4,
      marginTop : -100,
  }

});
```

I have added `marginTop` : -100 to make it look like the structure I want.

[image: Screenshot]

So this is what it looks like right now after adding marginTop to -100, But that's not responsive, When I increase the size of that white block. It doesn't stay in center anymore.

Need Help on how to do that :(

Comment: It would help if you posted your rendered code, not your templates, so we can help more fully/directly. Having said that, you can check out this great css tricks post https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ and click "Both Horizontally and Vertically" to center your div. If you don't need too much backwards compatibility do flexbox, otherwise use one of the other options ther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using percentage instead of logical pixels like in this example :

```
const WindowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headerBackground}/>
      <View style={styles.header}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  headerBackground: {
    height: '30%',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor : 'blue'
  },
  header: {
    height: '30%',
    width: '80%',
    marginTop: WindowHeight * -0.15,
    backgroundColor : 'white'
  }
});
```

In this example I set the height of the blue background and the white header to 30% of the window's height, and the marginTop to -15% of the window's height (I have to use **Dimensions** because [if I use a percentage it'll be the percentage of the width...](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties))

You can run my example on snack : https://snack.expo.io/Hyd7ChplX

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your profileDataContainer in your coverContainer and place it absolute with top 50%. Hope you can convert it yourself to your React Native code...

Example:

```css
.coverContainer{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.profileDataContainer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="coverContainer"><div class="profileDataContainer"></div></div>
```